# .css() function not adding css transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to add an piece of CSS code to an element while scrolling. However it is not being added. Yet when I do it through the developer console it works.

```
if ($('header').hasClass('header-horizontal-stacked')){
    menu.css({
        'transform': '-' + headerTopHeight + 'px'
    });
}
```

If i use  like this it the console shows `68` which is correct:

```
if ($('header').hasClass('header-horizontal-stacked')) {
    console.log(headerTopHeight)
}
```

If i use this it also works.

```
if ($('header').hasClass('header-horizontal-stacked')) {
    console.log("ok!");
}
```

What is the problem with the first one?

Comment: what is `menu`? It is a class or id?

Comment: Check CSS transform http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: transform comes with additional properties like translate/rotate etc..

Comment: What do you expect it to do? `transform: -68px` isn't meaningful...

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Try to do: menu.css('background-color', '#ff0') to see if it works
2. If it does the problem is probably in missing the translateY(or whatever you are doing with the transform)

   ```
   menu.css({'transform': 'c(-' + headerTopHeight + 'px)'    });
   ```